# How to make Portal 2 style transitions?

Tags: after-effects

I just want to ask you if there is a good way how to make Portal 2 menu style "panels" transitions in After effects.
You can see the transition [here](http://i.imgur.com/8c8ApgT.gifv) (*Imgur link*)

Thank you for your help. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Card Dance effect [AE Help link](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/simulation-effects.html#card_dance_effect)

Comment: That looks great. I'l try do it this way. Thank you ;)